# jQuery select box increase value, only target next select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple script that increases and decreases the selected values of a select box:

```
$(".inc").click(function(){
    $("select option:selected").next().prop("selected", true);
});
$(".dec").click(function(){
    $("select option:selected").prev().prop("selected", true);
});
```

However, I have 20 selects in one form, and dont want to have to repeat the script with new #ids to only associate the script with the next select box (e.g select#1, sesect#2 ....)

At present, when the user clicks inc or dec on any select box, ALL select values in the form are updated, not just one.

Anyone know how to target only the next, immediate select box when the script is executed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is .inc in relation to the select menu? Is there 20 inc's as well as 20 select menus?

If the structure is:

```
<div class="inc">increment</div>
<select><option></option><option></option></select>
```

You should be able to use

```
$(".inc").click(function(){
$(this).next('select > option:selected').next().prop("selected", true);
});
```

Updated: Note that use of .next() depends on your HTML structure. Using siblings() is properly better. See here for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/JZJZh/

Comment: Hi, Yes - there are twenty buttons with class "inc" and twenty with class "dec" - should this still work?

Comment: Yes it would have still worked, but next() gets only the IMMEDIATELY following DOM element, so if you have `<div class="inc"></div><div class="dec"></div>` then only the 'dec' one would have worked. I've modified my script to use 'siblings' (so they'll work provided they're in the same DOM hierarchy. Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/JZJZh/.